# Debian server locked - find_busiest_group?

Tags: linux, debian, kernel-panic, proxmox

Just wondering if anyone sees any clues from the following screen shot as to what might have caused this server to lock up:

[image: debian server crash]

This server also locked up 6 months ago, and I still have the screen shot from that too:

[image: debian server crash from six months ago]

The server is running Proxmox 1.8 (which is based on Debian Lenny, but a kernel that I think comes from OpenVZ). uname output (host name masked):

Linux ------ 2.6.32-4-pve #1 SMP Mon May 9 12:59:57 CEST 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Does anyone see any clues based on these screen shots as to whether this is a hardware or software issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a [kernel divide by zero bug](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=16991) that was [fixed in version 3.1.5](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.0/ChangeLog-3.1.5). [A patch is available](http://lkml.org/lkml/2011/12/19/35) if you want to attempt to backport it.

Comment: Thanks, I think you're right.  I'll go see if the Proxmox and OpenVZ developers have anything to say about this.  The latest Proxmox / OpenVZ releases are based on 2.6.32. :-(